# Add Datepicker field choice to Event Tickets Plus plugin

Tags: plugin-development, the-events-calendar, plugin-events-calendar

I'm using Events Tickets and Events Tickets Plus to create tickets on a site.

I have a field whereby users can choose a date using a datepicker to choose a date for their ticket for theatre tickets:

```
<?php if ( has_term( 'Theatre', 'product_cat', $ticket->ID ) ) {
    echo '<td class="tickets_date">';
    echo '<input placeholder="Select your date..." type="text" class="theatre-datepicker" name="date_'. $ticket->ID .'" />';

} ?>
```

I then have a plugin which does the following:

```
////// STEP: 1 - Process the custom data
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', function ( $cart_item_data, $ticket, $variation_id  ) {

  $cart_item_data['date'] = sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['date_'.$ticket->ID] );
  $cart_item_data['ukey'] = md5( microtime().rand() );

  return $cart_item_data;

}, 1, 3 );


// STEP 2: Display the custom data in cart / checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', function ( $cart_data, $cart_item ){

  $custom_items = array();

  if ( isset( $cart_item['date'] ) ) {

    $custom_items[] = array(
        'name' => 'Date',
        'value' => $cart_item['date'],
    );
  }

  return $custom_items;

}, 10, 2 );


// STEP 3: Save and display custom data (admin order meta / emails)
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', function ( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
if ( isset( $values['date'] ) ) {
    wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id,'Date', $values['date'] );
}
}, 10, 3 );
```

Now, this used to work on previous version of either Event Tickets plugin or the WooCommerce plugin, but now while I can show the field, it isn't saving against the ticket when the user adds the ticket to the cart, nor the checkout and nor the order.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Bumping this - still need assistance if anyone can help?